# How to define signalR MapHub route in a multi-Tenant application

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

SignalR ChatHub is defined as a controller.

```
[Route("{tenantName}/chatHub")]
public class ChatHub: Hub
```

In startup configure method,

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
 routes.MapHub<MessageHub>("/dev/chatHub");
});
```

This works fine in development environment.

My question is, how can useSignalR method be defined so that mapHub path is independent of the tenant or there is a different way to define so as to work on all the tenants like `$"/{tenant}/chatHub"`?

Comment: Have you tried that?

Comment: @davidfowl, not sure how to pass tenantName as a variable in the startup.

Comment: @davidfowl, startup.routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/{tenantName}/chatHub"); didn't work

Comment: Can you file an issue with the exception you got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've handled the issue in the following way;
Created chatHub controller without a tenant like

```
[Route("/chatHub")]
public class ChatHub: Hub
```

and in the startup.cs defined as

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
 {
     routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
 });
```

So this way common instance is handling all the tenants call and identifying tenants by method arguments like

public async Task SendMessage(string tenant, string message)
{
   ...
}

Answer (score -2):

I have been looking at this and if you are using Finbuckle as your Multitenant library you can use the following to specify your Route

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
     routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/{__tenant__}/chatHub");
});
```

Comment: This doesn't currently work, but I am still investigating so will post back when I have a solution