# Move signalR hub routing to controller

Tags: .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

In .Net Core app all routing is configured in controllers, but if you add signalR to your service you specify route in `startup.cs` as following:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
        });
```

Is it possible to move this routing to controller and use `Route` attribute?

Comment: The SignalR Hubs API enables you to call methods on connected clients from the server.  _Is it possible to move this routing to controller and use Route attribute?_ Did you mean to map Hub to specific route ? This thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51699068/how-to-define-signalr-maphub-route-in-a-multi-tenant-application may be helpful